# Browser Plugin query on Android Platform (Froyo 2.2.1 release)

Tags: android, plugins

I 'm interested to develop a browser plugin

**a.  Based on NPAPI framework

   b.  To be used with Android native web browser

   c.  On Froyo or later Android versions.**

There is a sample code for Browser plugin under Gingerbread
repository : /development/samples/BrowserPlugin/

I 'm able to build the code and install the *.apk on my targets
Android-Froyo or Android-Gingerbread (mobiles). However, the plugin
never gets detected with simple html test page that embeds the sample
plugin.

Do I need special privileges to be able to detect plugins ? Is the
solution to develop browser plugins feasible on Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if now Android doesn’t allow permission for foreign plugins to work on release binaries and it only works for eng releases.the plug-in API is not yet ready for general use, and requires a significant trust relationship between the plug-in author and platform (because the plug-in code is loaded directly in to the browser, which is why the browser will only load plug-ins signed by certificates it trusts)